# Use Grep to find blocks of text between two phrases (including the phrases)

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, bbedit

Is it possible to use grep to high lite all of the text starting with:

```
mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
```

and ending with:

```
CGPathAddPath(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath);
```

Where there is an arbitary amount of text in between those two phrases?

NOTE: I have to use grep because I'm using BBEdit.

Comment: You want to grep the text between those lines?

Comment: @qtax - nah I wrote it wrong, I need the text in between the phrases, as well as the two enclosing phrases.

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider: Updated my answer. HTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `GNU grep`:

```
grep -oPz 'mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable\(\);.*?(\n.*?)*.*?CGPathAddPath\(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath\);' file
```

If you don't have `GNU grep`, you could use `pcregrep` to achieve the same thing:

```
pcregrep -M 'mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable\(\);.*(\n|.)*CGPathAddPath\(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath\);' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed instead like this:

```
sed -n '/mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();/,/CGPathAddPath(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath);/p' infile
```

**EDIT:**

Not sure if `-P` flag of grep is supported in BBEdit. If it is then you can use this:

```
grep -oP 'mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();\X*CGPathAddPath(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath);/' infile
```

As per grep man page:

> -P, --perl-regexp
>        Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.

Comment: I have to use grep because Im using BBedit (sorry forgot to mention)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the lines between and including these you could use:

```
perl -ne '/start line/ .. /end line/ and print'
```