# grab a block of text between two tags, and append following lines if block contains certain tags

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I am trying to grab a block of text between tags.
The start tag will be identified with a regex match and the endtag will be static.

I have indeed searched for some ways to do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638546/use-grep-to-find-blocks-of-text-between-two-phrases-including-the-phrases) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206620/grepping-out-a-block-of-text-regex) although I could not found a solution for the problem that I am facing, as it has a few more specific conditions...
Let me give an example of the text file that I have:

```
<...text-to-ignore...>
tag_list_index
    tag1 ...................... 51
    tag2 .............. 54
    tagn ......... 243
    <...lots-of-text-to-ignore...>
        tag1
        headerA headerB headerC
        fieldx  description ...
        fieldy  description ... (a)
        fieldw  description ... 
        fieldz  description ... (c)
        fieldt  description ... (b)
                        Máx: 234+var
        (a) - Note1
        (b) - Note2
        (c) - Note3
        <...more-text-to-ignore...>
        tag2
        headerA headerB headerC
        fielda  description ...
        fieldj  description ... (a)
                        Max: 234+var
        (a) - Note1
        <...more-text-to-ignore...>
        tagn
        headerA headerB headerC
        fieldr  description ...
        fieldg  description ... 
                    Máx: 234+var
        <...more-text-to-ignore...>
```

So the purpose is to grab the text between *tagn* and the next line with  *M**á**x:*  or  *M**a**x:* ; plus the *notes* that are in the lines immediatly after the end tag, that is of course, if there are any in the grabbed block of text.
Indeed, the output would be:

```
        tag1
        headerA headerB headerC
        fieldx  description ...
        fieldy  description ... (a)
        fieldw  description ... 
        fieldz  description ... (c)
        fieldt  description ... (b)
                        Máx: 214+var
        (a) - Note1
        (b) - Note2
        (c) - Note3
        tag2
        headerA headerB headerC
        fielda  description ...
        fieldj  description ... (a)
                        Max: 13
        (a) - Note1
        tagn
        headerA headerB headerC
        fieldr  description ...
        fieldg  description ... 
                        Máx: 23+var
```

Can you help me out? 
No specific requirements with the tool to use.

Comment: How does the `A[0-9]{3}` fall into place? I see no line starting with space followed by an `A` ??

Comment: Well the tags actually follow that pattern. They will be something like "A123 - A Description" or "A999 : Another description". The reason why i didn't mentioned that in advance, was because i am able to  do the regex to grab those. Still I will edit the question to mention that. Thanks

Comment: Does it work as desired?

Comment: Yes, It worked like a charm! I will indeed, accept the solution. The restriction is ok, since there will always be text between notes and the next tag. Thanks very much for your help, and sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Everyone, you if downvote this question, please leave a comment on why. Downvoting without anyfurther explanation, does not help to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -nr '/^ +tag[0-9n]+$/,/M[áa]x: /p;:A;s/^        \([a-z]\)/&/;tB;b;:B;p;n;bA' file.txt
```

Output:

```
   tag1
    headerA headerB headerC
    fieldx  description ...
    fieldy  description ... (a)
    fieldw  description ... 
    fieldz  description ... (c)
    fieldt  description ... (b)
                    Máx: 234+var
    (a) - Note1
    (b) - Note2
    (c) - Note3
    tag2
    headerA headerB headerC
    fielda  description ...
    fieldj  description ... (a)
                    Max: 234+var
    (a) - Note1
    tagn
    headerA headerB headerC
    fieldr  description ...
    fieldg  description ... 
                Máx: 234+var
```

Restriction: If there is one note or multiple notes then `<...more-text-to-ignore...>` is important before next tag.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Cyrus. But there is another restriction, which is if the tag does not have any notes, it will not be able to grab the block, since you are relying on the existence of these notes. You may see that in the example I gave in which tagn does not have any note associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer is accepted, as it did accomplished the purpose, it was not clear for me at first how sed was doing the job. I have indeed looked into it a little bit further and have reshaped that command so it gets more clear for me while reading it.
I am sharing it, along with some comments on each command, in case it comes useful to anyone else.

```
sed -nr '/START/,/END/  {
 #print the block of text delimited by START and END
 p
 #Label A is stated
 :A
 # Substitutes all notes (a),(b),(c),... by them self. Meaning (a) is
 # substituted by (a), (b) by (b) and so on. Indeed, nothing is done.
 # This is a trigger for the next command... 
 s/^\([a-z]\)/&/
 # Command t will jump to label B (case insensitive), 
 # if any substitution was performed.
 tb
 # A branch without a label in front is saying: go to the end of script
 b
 #Label B is stated
 :B
 #prints the line
 p
 #Prints the current line and reads the next one
 n
 # Go up to label A again
 bA
 }' file.txt
```